# How to make a NodeJS Server that emits a string file line by line with a time interval when connected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-stream

I am trying to implement a simple NodeJS server that reads a file and then emits line by line to the requester with a time interval between emissions. The problem is the timeout which is not working as intended.

```
var http = require('http');
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log('request was made: '+req.url);

  res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname+"/foo.txt", 'utf8');

  var rl= readline.createInterface({
    input: myReadStream
  });

  rl.on('line', function(input) {

    res.write(input);
    setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);

  });

});


server.listen(3000,'127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there you just need to move the `res.write(line)` into your `setTimeout()` so the call to `res.write(line)` happens when the timeout callback is invoked.

```
rl.on('line', line => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.write(line);
  }, 3000);
});
```

Also you should listen for the `'close'` event from `readline` to know when you can call `res.end()` to end the response stream.

```
rl.on('close', () => {
  res.end();
});
```